# Rails4 Sales Transaction History Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm looking for a solution to record sales transactions.  Currently if I modify the price of a product, it will change the value of a previous sale because it is generated dynamically.  How do I create a history table so these transactions are stored?  Is there a gem for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the price to remain constant in the sales table you should copy the price over to a price column in the sales table. However, if this isn't what you want and you really need a history of versions on the products table use a versioning gem such as:

- https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail
- a bunch more here: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Versioning

What these typically do is create a versions table and (once you add the versioning declaration in your model) they will save a diff of your versioned model every time it gets updated.

Comment: unfortunately.  I have many types of products that are in their own relations and tables.  Also a main line item has sub line items. So it's not as easy as recording a price in the line_item table.

Comment: Just offering multiple options. Just go with a versioning gem then

Comment: I appreciate your help.  The options you gave are spot on

Answer (score 0):

Try using this gem: https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited

It's a gem that track all changes to your model.

It seems that audited isn't supported for Rails 4. This is also a good alternative: https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for.  That's good for seeing what user made changes to what table.   I need the ability when I look at a sale, I can simply call a version of the model that has values for that date.

Comment: Ok. Could you show your model relations/controller. There could be an easy custom solution for this.